# Starting a GUI application on the login screen prior to login

Tags: debian, login, gui, autostart

I have a server (VM) with Debian 10 and Cinamon desktop.

I want to autostart a GUI application at boot with a local user account **without** using autologin. And I want the application to use the display where the login screen is already shown.

The GUI application **must not** run as root, but shall use the already existing X session.

I got it working by *reusing* the X11 socket at "/var/run/lightdm/root/:0", but this is more a hack than a solution, because of the access rights.
Normally this socket is owned by root and has access rights 600. So I added a new group "accessx" to the system and put my user into this group.
Then I modified the group and access rights of "/var/run/lightdm/root" to 770 and "/var/run/lightdm/root/:0" to 660.

As a final step I did set

```
export XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0
export DISPLAY=:0
```

and started the GUI application, which was displayed on top of the login screen.

Beside that I needed to "hijack" the X11 socket of root, the access rights are reset when I really login/logout to the machine.

I tried another solution with xhost, but didn't get the access rights to the login screen display.

And I really want to re-use the existing X11 login screen, because this is a VM and when I connect to the virtual display, I want to see the application immediately.